# is.null on lists vs. other objects

Tags: r

Consider the following scenario:

```
demo <- list()
is.null(demo$first)
is.null(undefined_object)
```

The first scenario returns `TRUE` as it's a `NULL` element of the list. Why doesn't `undefined_object` return `NULL` as it's not an object in the global environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need a similar `TRUE` option, one option is to reference that object with `.GlobalEnv` and check if it is `NULL`

```
is.null(.GlobalEnv$undefined_object)
#[1] TRUE
```

with OP's example, we are checking whether the 'first' is `NULL` in the environment of 'demo' object which is already created, but the `undefined_object` is not created and thus we can check it in context with the global environment

```
is.null(demo$first)
#[1] TRUE
is.null(.GlobalEnv$demo$first)
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

`demo$first` calls the function `$`, and that function returns `NULL` if the right hand argument is not found.

`undefined_object` is not a function call, it's just the name of an object, but that object doesn't exist.

If you just print the two expressions, you'll see that they are different:

```
> demo$first
NULL
> undefined_object
Error: object 'undefined_object' not found
```

So when you put them in the `is.null()` call, you get different results, as you saw.